# DRF pass data into RelatedField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer and a related field for generic foreign key relationship 
that should be used to serialize `content_object` which is a `ContentType` instance. I need to check the `type` of the `Notification` object that I'm serializing inside the related field to properly know which additional fields to serialize into the `data` parameter in there. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
class NotificationRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        data = {}
        # Need to check notification 'type' here
        return data


class NotificationRetrieveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content_object = NotificationRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Notification
        fields = [
            'id',
            'created_at',
            'is_read',
            'type',
            'content_object',
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could serializer generic FK relation by using [**`SerializerMethodField`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) as,

```
class Content_Model_1_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # you code
class Content_Model_2_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # your code

class NotificationRetrieveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content_object = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_content_object(self, notification):
        if isinstance(notification.content_object, Content_Model_1):
            return Content_Model_1_serializer(notification.content_object).data
        if isinstance(notification.content_object, Content_Model_2):
            return Content_Model_2_serializer(notification.content_object).data
        ## and so on
        return None  # default case

    class Meta:
        model = Notification
        fields = [
            'id',
            'created_at',
            'is_read',
            'type',
            'content_object',
        ]
```

`Content_Model_1` and `Content_Model_2` are the models which are related by generic FK relation and `Content_Model_1_serializer` and `Content_Model_2_serializer` are thire serializer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the serializer's `to_representation` method to call the field's `to_representation` method with the `Notification` instance, rather than the value of the field.

**Example**:

```
class NotificationRetrieveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content_object = NotificationRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Notification
        fields = [
            'id',
            'created_at',
            'is_read',
            'type',
            'content_object',
        ]

    # override to_representation method
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        # python3 for `super` call
        result = super().to_representation(instance)

        # python2 for `super` call
        # result = super(
        #     NotificationRetrieveSerializer, self
        # ).to_representatio(instance)

        # here you call your field's `to_representation` with current instance
        # as the argument rather than as the `value` of the field.
        result['content_object'] = content_object_field.to_representation(instance)

        return result

class NotificationRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):

    # here `value` is now the `Notification` instance
    def to_representation(self, value):
        data = {}

        # get the type and this field's value
        type = value.type
        content_object = value.content_object

        return data
```